# Is there a way to expand bash history references such as `!:0-` before executing without using the p option?

Tags: bash

There are multiple reasons why this is useful, including the ability to use shell completion to add a final argument to the command and the ability to see what command you are about to run without using the p option and needing to retype the history reference with an updated time value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works to always expand after you hit a space:

```
cat >> ~/.inputrc
$if Bash
    " ": magic-space
$endif
```

Comment: I just saw that a common .bashrc binding is `bind Space:magic-space`. Seems to work well.

Comment: this is awesome, I've been looking for this for years!  I was a tcsh holdout because the history tab completion works so well.  I didn't think that bash could do anything like it.  But thanks to this tip, I can now have something close:  `Tab: magic-space`

Comment: Doh! So close yet so far.  Turns out setting magic-space to Tab overrides the normal Tab completion.  So lame, bash, so lame.  Anyone know if its possible to make bash completion and magic-space both coexist using Tab?  That's how it works in `tcsh` and its wonderful.